# How To Create A UITextField With The Ability To Function Like A UIButton?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having a problem with creating a nice layout with accomplishing what I want. I want to have a question (I don't need help with this) and 4 answer choices below. I have created these answer choices as Text Fields because that allows me to get a nice border to it that is thin and like I want it to be. But I also want this to be uneditable at the same time clickable. What I mean by this is that the user cannot edit an answer, but when they click on the right answer, the border becomes green or something. I have searched so much, but I always get errors and it never works.

This is an example of the type of layout I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxGwh.png).

I can't make this into a button because it has really ugly and square borders, but I can't do UITextView because I can't make an @IBAction and change specific attributes when clicked. I can't do UITextField because when I click a text field, it doesn't do anything. I can't turn off User Interaction Enabled because then they won't be able to click it. How can I make it work so that it will become like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESGpm.png) when clicked but maintains this same format?

(Don't worry about font differences and all.)

I don't have any code to show because there is nothing I have found to work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use UIButton property, selected and unselected. it will help you

Comment: What do you mean by that, Abuzar Manzoor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a custom `UIButton` class.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    }
}
```

That will get you a button with a border and inset which looks like what you are trying to achieve:

[image]

A good way of checking whether the correct answer button is tapped would be to use the `tag` property on the `UIButton`.  For example, 0 for the wrong answer, 1 for the correct answer.  You can then check the tag value when each button is pressed.  (all buttons connected to the same `IBAction`).  If the correct button is pressed, you can set the border color to green, and do whatever else you need, before repeating the cycle.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var answerAButton: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet var answerBButton: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet var answerCButton: CustomButton!
    @IBOutlet var answerDButton: CustomButton!

    var answerButtons: [UIButton]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        answerButtons = [answerAButton, answerBButton, answerCButton, answerDButton]
        setCorrectAnswer()
    }

    func setCorrectAnswer() {
        answerButtons.forEach {
            // Reset the border on each button
            $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
            // Reset the tag on each button
            $0.tag = 0
        }

        // Set the correct answer button tag
        answerButtons[2].tag = 1
    }

    @IBAction func answerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

*Answering your additional questions:*

***1. Where would I put the Custom Button?***

***2. What type of file should I create for that?***

1. Create a Swift file, named **CustomButton.swift** (or whatever you want to call it).
2. In Storyboard use a standard UIButton, and in the Identity Inspector change the custom class to match.  Make sure that the `IBOutlets` for your buttons are of type `CustomButton` for your `IBOutlet` connection.  As shown above.  You will not see the effects in Storyboard, only at runtime.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Where would I put the Custom Button? What type of file should I create for that?

Comment: You're welcome.  I've updated my answer to answer your two further questions.

Comment: Thank you again! I do have another question. In the last IBAction - answerTapped, what is that connected to? Where is that action connected to? Or will I have to make that action 4 times for 4 answers?

Comment: One idea is to create an answerSelected IBAction and connect all of the buttons to it. The problem is that I need to say (inside of that) if answerSelected == answer2 {}, but I can't because answerSelected is the IBAction and it doesn't work. So when I group all of these inside answerSelected, I can't check which answer they selected. Do you know a way to accomplish that?

Comment: My answer shows you how to do that.  Yes - connect one `IBAction` to all the answer buttons.  `UIButton` has a settable `tag` property.  In my answer I suggested setting this to 0 for each button with the wrong answer and 1 for the button with the correct answer.  You can then check this in the `IBAction` and handle it accordingly. `sender.tag`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plain view, where you can adjust the border and corner radius to make it look how you want it. Put a label inside of it and again set the styling you need/want. To detect touch you could either put a button over it (without any text, so it's not visible) or you could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view and use it to detect taps.

This is how you would achieve the desired border look on a view:

```
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
```

And this is how you would add a gesture recognizer:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gestureRecognized(gesture:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

// Somewhere below in code put the method that is called when gesture is recognized
@objc
func gestureRecognized(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Gesture recognized
}
```

Here is a short example how you should set things up:

```
import UIKit

protocol AnswerViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func answerViewUserDidTap(sender: AnswerView)
}

class AnswerView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: AnswerViewDelegate?

    private lazy var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGestureRecognized(gesture:)))

    var answerId: String?
    var answer: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

        addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc private func tapGestureRecognized(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.answerViewUserDidTap(sender: self)
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var answerView1: AnswerView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var answerView2: AnswerView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var answerView3: AnswerView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var answerView4: AnswerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This is just for demonstration purposes, to keep the code as short as possible
        [answerView1, answerView2, answerView3, answerView4].enumerated().forEach { offset, answerView in
            answerView?.answerId = String(offset)
            answerView?.answer = "Answer number: \(offset)"
            answerView?.delegate = self
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - AnswerViewDelegate

extension ViewController: AnswerViewDelegate {

    func answerViewUserDidTap(sender: AnswerView) {
        print("User tapped answer: \(String(describing: sender.answerId)) with id: \(String(describing: sender.answerId)).")
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It didn't fully work, though. I told it to print("Great, it worked!") in the console if it made the gesture recognized. It didn't print anything. Is there somewhere I have to call this function maybe?

Comment: No there isn't anything else to do/call. You added the gesture to the view that you want to detect tap on right? Could you maybe prepare a short gist to demonstrate how did you set it up?

Comment: I put the Outlets and all right after the `class ____: UIViewController`. I also have the tap gesture recognizer definition placed just before viewDidLoad. Inside viewDidLoad, I put the border color, border-radius and all. Right after those three border definitions, I `.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`. Then after the viewDidLoad, I put the @objc func, printing out "Great, it worked!" if it went into that code. But it never printed "Great, it worked" to the terminal. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you might have two problems. The first is that you need to define the tap gesture recognizer in a different way. Either as a property on your view (as you mentioned above) but you should define it as `lazy var` or you define the gesture in `viewDidLoad`, just before adding it to the view. Another thing is that you probably want to have a gesture recognizer for every answer view. It is possible to solve this with just one gesture recognizer but the solution is a bit more complex. See my edited answer above for an example. Copy the code in a new project and try it out. Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

First create outlet for all button, see the image below

[image: Selected image]

[image: Image with un selected image]

then

```
@IBAction func languageSelectionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    englishBtn.isSelected = false
    FrenchBtn.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true      
}
```